# Из полноэкранного режима в оконный и наоборот

Tags: c#, winapi, .net

Нужно программно перевести игру в полноэкранный режим и наоборот из полноэкранного в оконный. Хэндл окна нахожу функцией **FindWindowByCaption**.
Если это возможно, покажите пожалуйста пример как это сделать. Спасибо.
P.s: сочетание клавиш Alt+Enter не срабатывает.

Перевести в полноэкранный режим у меня получилось так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);

public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong)
{
    return IntPtr.Size == 8
        ? SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong)
        : new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong));
}

public static void SetWindowFullScreen(string windowName)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, windowName);

    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOPMOST);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
```

А вот из полноэкранного обратно в оконный не получается :(

Answer (score 2):

Для такого рода задач существует утилита Spy ++ с помощью нее можете посмотреть значение окна и уже на основании этих данных производить поиск этого окна.
Spy ++ идет в комплекте со студией
Пример работы [пример]:http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы устанавливаете свои значения стилей, полностью игнорируя изначальные значения. Обычно стили добавляют с помощью `OriginalStyle |= ExtraStyle` и удаляют с помощью `OriginalStyle &= ~ExtraStyle`. Это, так сказать, правило хорошего тона, чтобы ничего не испортить.

Чтобы проделать эти операции, нужно сначала получить исходные значения. А чтобы восстановить исходные значения, нужно эти исходные значения сохранить. Так что вперёд и с песней к `GetWindowLong`.